# Ubuntu in VirtualBox wants to install on every boot

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 using Virtual Box in my Windows XP. I have use Ubuntu 11.10 iso to install it. First time when I installed every thing was fine but when I shutdown the VirtualBox and start Ubuntu again, it asks me to install Ubuntu and try Ubuntu without installing.

Do I need to do some extra settings?

Answer (score 15):

The installer is not automatically ejecting the virtual CD. Open "Device" menu, then go to "CD/DVD Devices" and you'll find "Remove disk from virtual drive".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also/alternatively change the boot order under **Settings** > **System**.

Click on Hard Disk and then the up arrow to make it the first item in the list:

[image]

Comment: This does not ultimately fix the issue, as it is advisable to still use the CD boot first as if this were a real system, in case you have to do some repairs via the live environment.  The other answer will explain virtual disk ejection though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the image from VirtualBox under *Settings → Storage → Controller*.